# how to remove already present data while making search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I had to integrate search engine in website. But there is already a list of data on first page.
my question is how this data should hide or remove when making a new search request.       !https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsW4Pb3Y55Qjb34OtQI7qQotLzc
In mention image let I enter something to search and upon hitting enter how the present elements should be removed.
I mean after getting successful response how can I remove the already present list of data on website.
I tried to find resources but no clue. If someone give me some directions, I will be thankful. I am completely new to ajax and jquery.

Code start :

$("#search").keyup(function(){

```
clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(update, 50);
```

});

function update() {
    clearInterval(timer);

```
var myInput = $("#search").val();
if ((myInput != "") && (myInput != searchText)) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search-start',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {"data": myInput},
        success: function (response) { 
            console.log(response);

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error.")
        }
```

Comment: is there a UI somewhere or are you just using the console?

Comment: there is UI.  I figure out the solution. might be I didn't explain my question correctly but the solution is .   $(".class").remove();    . nd it will delete the list items from the page. .

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions

```
<div id="data-container"> <!-- main container which holds your data list -->
   <ul id="data-list"> <!-- list of data here -->
      <li>Data 1</li>
      <li>Data 2</li>
      <!--- ...other datas --->
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search-start',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {"data": myInput},
        success: function (response) { 
            if(/**response contains correct data**/){
               $('#data-list').html(''); // empty the data list

               //prepare the data list view like

               var newDataList = "";

               $.each(response['data'], function(key, val){
                  newDatalist += "<li>"+val+"</li>";
               });

               // then append your new data to the data list
               $('#data-list').html(newDataList);

            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error.")
        }
     });
```